# Trying to add the sum of a field, from a txt file, without using panda

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to get the sum of field 5 from my program.
It opens a txt file, displays name, item, price of item, quantity sold and then computes the total sale for that person. I cant seem to get how to find the sum of the computed totals and then display it at the end of the program.

```py
def getTotal():
    sum(personTotal)
    return total

    

def main():

    print("%-8s %-21s %-6s %10s %14s" % ("Name", "Item", "Price", "Quantity", "Person Total"))  
    
    f = open("makewaves.txt", "r")                          
    
    for line in f:
        name, item, price, quantity = line.split(",")
        
        price = float(price)
        
        quantity = int(quantity)
        
        personTotal = float(price) * float(quantity)

        total = getTotal

        print()
        print("%-8s %-21s $%-5.2f %6d %14.2f" % (name, item, price, quantity, personTotal))
        print()
       
    print(" Total sales are : " + "$" + str(total))

main()
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code. First, you have an indentation error in the `getTotal()` function. Second, you never actually call your `getTotal()` function. Third, your `getTotal()` function doesn't even take a parameter. Fourth, your `getTotal()` function doesn't actually return the sum.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using Pandas?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, please accept it so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version of your code. It wasn't clear what you were trying to do with `total = getTotal` so I removed it and the `getTotal()` function altogether.

In order to get the total sales, you need to run an accumulator by initializing an accumulator variable outside the loop, and then incrementing the accumulator variable by each person's `personTotal`:

```py
def main():
    print("Name     Item                  Price    Quantity   Person Total")  
    sale_string = "\n{:8s} {:21s} ${:5.2f} {:6d} {:14.2f}\n"
    
    total_sales = 0  # initialize an accumulator variable
    with open("makewaves.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            name, item, price, quantity = line.split(",")
            price = float(price)
            quantity = int(quantity)
            personTotal = price * quantity

            total_sales += personTotal  # add to the total_sales accumulator
            
            print(sale_string.format(name, item, price, quantity, personTotal))
    
    print("Total sales: ${total_sales}")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've converted your old style string formatting to a nicer version, and also got rid of the header format string since that didn't need to be dynamic.

Note that I've also changed your code to use a `with` block for reading your file. The `with` block is what's known as a context manager, and closes the file automatically after the block is exited.

I've also added the `if __name__ == "__main__"` pattern, which simply makes it so that when you run this script as a standalone Python file, it calls the `main()` function, but if you were to import this script into another Python file, the `main()` function won't get called automatically.